# Is there a less verbose way to get a default string from a vector of strings?

Tags: string, rust

I've tried using `&str` instead of `String`, but that has compilation errors. I ended up with:

```
fn main()
{
    let words: Vec<String> = vec!["apple".to_string(), "orange".to_string(), "banana".to_string()];
    let word: String = match words.get(4)
    {
        Some(s) => s.to_string()
        , None => "nil".to_string()
    };
    println!("word: {}", word);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things that will immediately help shorten this program:

1. Type inference: you very rarely have to write types out
2. `&str`: way too many calls to `to_string` here

I would write it as:

```
fn main() {
    let words = vec!["apple", "orange", "banana"];
    let word = match words.get(4) {
        Some(&s) => s,
        None => "nil"
    };
    println!("word: {}", word);
}
```

Note that `Vec<T>::get` returns an `Option<&T>`, thus here an `Option<&&str>`, since we want `s` to be of type `&str` (single `&`), we use `Some(&s)` as the pattern. Another option would be `Some(s) => *s,` (here, having `s` be `&&str` and dereferencing it).

Of course, this can all be further reduced by looking at the specific API of [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). Somewhat less universal, but `Option` and `Result` are very often used in Rust (so much they are in the prelude!!!) and therefore it's worth learning their APIs.

In this case `unwrap_or` will provide either the value inside `Option` or the value passed to it:

```
fn main() {
    let words = vec!["apple", "orange", "banana"];
    let word = *words.get(4).unwrap_or(&"nil");
    println!("word: {}", word);
}
```

Bit of reference juggling to line-up the types (aka type Tetris) and it's all good.

Comment: Very nice and clear.  I missed the `Some(&s)` in my first try with `&str`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure, what you want to achieve, but this is probably the best way to do exactly what you did in your code:

```
fn main() {
    let words = vec!["apple", "orange", "banana"];
    let word = words.get(4).cloned().unwrap_or("nil").to_string();
    println!("word: {}", word);
}
```

The tricky part is `cloned()`: the `get()` method will return an optional reference to the value inside of the vector. But since the vector already holds references, we end up with `Option<&&str>` (two references). The `cloned()` call removes one reference, thus we have `Option<&str>`.

Also note that in this example the final `to_string()` call isn't necessary -- we can do everything only with `&str`.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to remember the coercion rules of [strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html) when deciding between `&str` and `String`.

```rust
fn main()
{
     let words = vec!["apple", "orange", "banana"]; // Vec<&str>
     let word = match words.get(2) {               // &str
         Some(&s) => s
         None => "nil"
     };
     println!("word: {}", word);
 }
```

You could consolidate the `words` and `word` matching code if length was still a concern for you, but I think this (perhaps including type annotations) is the most succinct without compromising clarity.